# Long string in PHP Mysql query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a database from a really long URL parameter that looks like this 44444444-44444444-33333333-33333333
When I echo the text to the page it looks correct but when I try it in the query string it always return the same result.
What can be causing this? 
Below is the php query.

```
}
   $colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
   if (isset($_GET['ZaP_SN'])) {
   $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['ZaP_SN'];

     echo $colname_Recordset1;
}
   mysql_select_db($database_MyDB, $MyDB);
   $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM assingments WHERE ZaP_SN = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
   $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $zaprompt) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
   $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query expression is:

```
WHERE ZaP_SN = %s
```

When you put the value in:

```
WHERE ZaP_SN = 44444444-44444444-33333333-33333333
```

This is interpreted as a numeric expression.  You have two solutions.  The less preferred way is to add in single quotes:

```
WHERE ZaP_SN = '%s'
```

The better way is to use parameters in the query to pass in the string.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by use parameters in the query to pass the string?

Comment: I have found out what is going wrong but I don't know how to fix it.  Something is happening to the number when the are passed between pages as a Parameter. They look the same, but if I type the parameter into the address bar myself it works, but when I submit it from another page it doesn't work.  What can be going one.

Comment: There was an extra character being passed in the parameter, this worked.  Thanks